# How to loop through all WebParts controls

Tags: 2013, web-part, asp.net, localization

There is a way I loop through all controls of my Sharepoint 2013 Visual WebPart, and only them? Something like this:

```
...
foreach(var _control in this.Controls)
{
    if (_control.typeof() == <Control with Text properties>)
        _control.Text = GetTranslation(_control.Text);
    if (_control.typeof() == <Control with InnerText properties>)
        _control.InnerText = GetTranslation(_control.InnerText);
}
...
```

As you can see, we need to translate all text in a webpart through a function (for specific reasons we cannot use Resources, please avoid comments on that).

Comment: Is it a visual webpart?

Comment: Yes, it is a visual WebPart, I'll edit the question to make it more clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the control collection using below code

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
    {
        if (childc is TextBox)
        {
            //Use childc.Text property
        }
        else if(childc is Label)
        {
            ...
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Amal, the way you presented I believe it would loop ALL controls in the whole page (Master pages, etc.), and I want to do it only in the WebPart controls.

Comment: tcbrazil: You can try it out. I believe it only give you the control belonging to your particular user control.

Comment: Yes, it loops through the webpart controls only, tks!